# Folder path before project

Tags: c#, path, directory

I am trying to get a folder path in my C drive that I did not want to hard code with my program.
I know that I can use `string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;` However its give me : `C:\FACE\Camera\Camera\bin\Debug` . Which I want to only have `C:\FACE\` as I want to initialise something in the FACE folder but outside of my Camera folder. I do not wish to hardcode the file path. Is it possible to do it? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the method `Directory.GetParent` for this purpose:

```
Directory.GetParent("here you will pass you path");
```

**Update**

For your case, you could take that you want as below:

```
string projectPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
string solutionPath = Directory.GetParent(projectPath).Parent.FullName;
string basePath = Directory.GetParent(solutionPath).FullName;
```

The variable `basePath` contains that you want.

Comment: What path should I put under "here you will pass you path" ?

Comment: `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Answer (score 0):

System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory always returns the path of executable assembly.You can use DTE if you are using web application